# How can I display the number of children model's records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Should I code something like this in view?

> **<%= @childrens.count %>**

or

**controller**

> **@children = Parent.children
>
>   @children_count = @children.count**

**view**

> **<%= @children_count%>**

or should I add one column called 'count' in Parent table, and every time user creates new CommunityTopic record, should I re-count the number of records and save the number to 'count ' column? at the same time, I'd like to update 'at_modified(TimeStamp)' of Parent table, when new CommunityTopic has been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute db requests in the controller, not in the view.
In your situation, counting the children could be done like so :

```
@children_count = Parent.children.count
```

And then display `@children` in your view :

```
<%= @children_count %>
```

By the way, check this link : http://web.archive.org/web/20100210204319/http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size It will give you additional information about when to use `count`, `size`, or `length`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What about adding the column called 'count' to Parent table? Isn't it faster to sort by the number of Children records?

Comment: I don't think so, first I don't know how you could handle this : "count" would be present in every record so which one will you update ? And basically you would have to execute an additional write request on the db I guess, each time... Not so good. FYI, "count" (as explained in the above link) creates a COUNT request on the db and avoids loading all the children in memory so it's pretty good and efficient at what it does.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I decided to use count as it is. Thank you so much!